# Client-Server app for Android/Java using dynamic IP

Tags: android, sockets, dynamic, client, ip

So i want to create an Android application that would send data (in this case coordinates) from my Android device to a Java application on my MacBook via Wi-Fi. 
I figured i would use TCP Sockets for the job, and my Android device would act as client while my MacBook as server.
My problem is that in reality hardcoding IP addresses is not the ideal techique for that, is there any way around this? Is using Sockets the best way to make an application like that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dynamic DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). With dynamic DNS, client (Macbook) registers its IP address with DNS server, which than serves it to other clients (Android) via normal DNS requests.

However, I'd recommend against this setup (server on notebook with DynDNS):

1. Your notebook might not be always available, due to personal reasons or network connectivity reasons.
2. Network address translation (NAT): most client networks (wlan, home networks, even mobile networks) use this technology which prevents initiating TCP connections from internet to internal network (inbound connections). This can be alleviated via port forwarding, but this can only be done on networks that you control.

Instead I'd suggest that you use a virtual private server (Linode) or a cloud solution.

Alternatively, if you don't want to setup/manage a server, than you could use an existing data exchange solution: email, twitter, xmpp, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Not getting into the best way to do it, but instead of static ips use a [Dynamic Dns Service](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/).

Comment: Just a reference to the "best" way? I would love to look it up.

Comment: Well i'd use something in the cloud like Google App Engine to not depend on a laptop in the setup.